# Is it possible to serve HTML dynamically in Shopify?

Tags: shopify, liquid

I'm thinking something like pulling in a json file and generating a page from it. I'm just wanting to know if this is a possibility in Shopify.

We're wanting to move our current site completely over to Shopify, and we're hoping we can still have much of the functionality we got from angular and node.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can do this through **Application proxies**.

> An application proxy is a feature that fetches and displays data on a
>   Shopify shop page from an outside location that you, the developer,
>   specify. For app developers, this means that the content on these
>   proxy pages can be dynamic; capable of being updated as much as you
>   feel necessary. App developers can use application proxies to display
>   image galleries, statistics and custom forms, just to name a few
>   examples.

Basically when Shopify receives an HTTP request on a proxied path, it forwards that request to your specified URL so you can do as you wish. Even further, if you set the `Content-Type: application/liquid` on your response headers, Shopify will render the template for you; so you could use your very own liquid templates making this page look and behave exactly as the rest of your shop.

There's information on how to get started on [the official Shopify Documentation.](https://help.shopify.com/api/tutorials/application-proxies)

Comment: Thanks. This sounds really useful.